# Windows Read shared folder permission

Tags: shared-folders

I was reading about Shared folder permissions and then I passed by the following information about the read permission :

> Read: Display folder names, file names, file data, and attributes; run
> application files; and change folders within the shared folder.

after testing I couldn't change anything inside the folder ,just viewing the files and run application , so does this info about read permission "`change folders within the shared folder`" wrong ?

Regards

Comment: I am guessing that this is the confusing behavior between NTFS ACL permissions and Share permissions (but I am too lazy to look it up right now).  These permissions sets are COMPLETELY different permissions sets that Microsoft married in Windows Vista called "Simplified Permissions".. both sets are still there but hidden in more complicated menus.  Keep in mind, two sets of permissions.. for instance, I can allow a user of a share FULL ACCESS and still prevent them from doing diddly squat using the NTFS ACL (file permissions).. this is a guess.. as I said I AM LAZY.

Comment: thanks mate , but i don't think this is the case because When you combine NTFS permissions and shared folder permissions, the resulting permission is the most restrictive permission of the combined shared folder permissions or the combined NTFS permissions , so if the user has read on the share permissions and modify on the NTFS permission , then he has the read only that's the most restrictive permissions and again in this case the read doesn't allow to change the folder contents or attributes  right ?

Comment: I believe that we are saying the same thing Mr Jack ;)  I just wanted to ensure that you understood what you were up against. :)